# Should I write "expertise I will have gained" or "expertise I have gained"?

Tags: sentence-construction, perfect-constructions, future-perfect

> "Using the teachings, skills and expertise I have gained through this course I’d like to produce..."

Do I need to add "I will have gained here" or rather not?

Even though skills are not yet acquired, to me it feels like now we are at the point after the class is taken not anymore here now. Adding will makes these using and will have a little contradictory to me in terms of time perspective.

What do you think?

Comment: By using ...expertise *provided* by this course... it will not matter if how far along (if at all) you are in the course.

Comment: thank you for your answer, why not "I will have gained" before starting to take the class to point the end of the class when I will have gained all the skills? also should I put "by" or can I skip it and just start "using".. why? thank you

Comment: Using *will have gained* is okay, but communicates that you will have them in the future. Using *provided* leaves this open for interpretation or discussion. The initial *by* is optional. :)

Comment: what do you mean by "leaves it open for interpretation or discussion"? when using provided do you assume or mean we omit the "I (will) have gained" part? thank you

Comment: I suggest "Using the teachings, skills and expertise **provided by** this course I’d like to produce..." because the use of "will have gained" communicates that you do not have them yet.

Comment: I would not use teachings, sounds religious. The word knowledge is better. For your information, your explanatory paragraph contains errors. You might try running it through Word.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not yet finished the course and so are talking about skills you will gain in the future once the course is completed, use "will."

If you have already finished the course and so have gained all skills the course will provide you, that is more in the past so do not use "will."

Answer (score 0):

I'd say either

> ...the skills I have gained in this course

or

> ...the skills I will gain in this course

They are close to interchangeable, in my opinion. I'd probably use the latter if the course hadn't started yet, and the former if I were partway through the course. Either would be correct, though.

You could add "so far" to make it clear with the former case that you haven't completed the course yet:

> ...the skills that I have gained so far in this course

Comment: thank you for your answer, why not "I will have gained" before starting to take the class to point the end of the class when I will have gained all the skills?

Answer (score 0):

> "Using the teachings, skills and expertise I have gained through this course I’d like to produce..."

As skills are not yet acquired, the phrase

> "I will have gained here"

should be better.

> "Using the teachings, skills[,] and expertise I *will have gained* through this course[,] I’d like to produce..."

I have also suggested a comma after 'skills' and another after 'course'.